# Submit Form to a Colorbox Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, colorbox

Im trying to submit this form to a Colorbox Iframe. any ideas to make it work please... the values are not passing through

```
<form action="newsletter/add.php" method="GET" onSubmit='$.colorbox({width:"90%", height:"60%", iframe:true, href:"newsletter/add.php"}); return false;'>
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
<input name="cellphone" type="text" placeholder="Celular">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUSCRIBIR" />
</form>
```

Comment: What's the problem you're facing exactly? Any Errors?

Comment: no errors,  the form values are no passing thru, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to handle the `onSubmit` event:

```
$.colorbox({width:"90%", height:"60%", iframe:true, href:"newsletter/add.php&" + $(this).serialize()}); return false;
```

Bear in mind that it's not a best practice to attach event handlers directly to the HTML element. You could improve this code by doing something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(form).on('submit', function(event) {
    $.colorbox({width:"90%", height:"60%", iframe:true, href:"newsletter/add.php&" + $(this).serialize()}); 
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pottersky/xeL5bm2e/1/

Comment: Hi, thank for the reply, the form values are no passing thru, any ideas ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this out of the box. You'll need a workaround. For ex., on submit, read the form values and concatenate to the 'href' string.